# If I accidentally write Hashem's name, can I fix it?

Tags: halacha, aleph-bet-letters, mistakes, shemos-sacred-names

Specifically, if  I intended to write a tzadei (צ) and I begin by making the two top yuds (') [Hashem's name] - can I complete my tzadei?

Answer (score 6):

Two yuds is not a Name of Hashem. It is just an abbreviation or "placeholder."

Comment: Right, but that means only that the example in the question is not a good one: the question remains, though, I think.

Comment: @msh210, you're right that the question remains, but I think that the type of mistake one needs to make to actually write a Divine Name accidentally is significantly different from and less probable than the letter-forming example that zaq described.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, how about writing the first two letters of _Y'chiel_ or _yichye_ and accidentally writing a _he_ instead of a _ches_?

Comment: @msh210 The classic case is writing יהודה and accidentally putting the leg into the Dalet.