# If you accidentally write the capitalized word "god", ought you delete the `o` and write a `-` in its place?

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names

This question didnt provide a sufficient answer.

[If I accidentally write Hashem's name, can I fix it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10288/if-i-accidentally-write-hashems-name-can-i-fix-it)

If its true, that

> he reason you don't write his name is so that nobody can destroy it.

and I assume to keep the commandment

> You shall not take the name of the L‑rd your G‑d in vain; for the L‑rd will not hold him guiltless that takes His name in vain.

When you put yourself in the situation accidentally where people can destroy it, do you destroy it yourself so that it does not risk further abuse?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the English writing "God" or about any name of God, including in Hebrew? You don't see people going around destroying siddurim; rather, we put them in geniza.

Comment: @magicker72 The English Writing. Thanks. `destroying siddurim; rather, we put them in geniza.` I dont know what this means.

Comment: Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genizah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabbi Soloveitchik explained that the English word G-O-D is not an actual name of Hashem. In fact, he wrote the word on the blackboard in Rambam Yeshiva and then erased it to show this. My source for this was from one of the students in his class who saw him do this.

Thus, it is perfectly permissable to do what you asked.
Many people use the number '0' rather than substituting '-' for the letter 'o' (such as in JewishWorldReview.com for its columnists) in order to prevent the various editors from putting the letters g and d on separate lines.

When we were writing the soc.culture.jewish FAQ we used the following question.

Note: The story below about Rav Soloveitchik was confirmed by a person who was in the class at Boston's Rambam high school when it occurred.

[Section - Question 11.3.1: Writing: Why do some people write "G-d" with a hyphen instead of an `o'?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/judaism/FAQ/05-Worship/section-52.html)

> Based on the words in Deut. 12:3-4, the Rabbis deduced that it is
> forbidden to erase the name of G-d from a written document. Since any
> paper upon which G-d's name was written might be discarded and thus
> "erased", the Rabbis forbade explicitly writing the name of G-d,
> except in Holy Books, with provisions for the proper disposal of such
> books.
>
> According to Jewish Folklore, G-d has 70 names. However, only one of
> these names is the ineffable name, which cannot be erased or
> pronounced. Further, of the 70 names, seven may not be erased but they
> can be pronounced on certain occasions (such as when reading the
> Torah). The other names may be erased and pronounced, but still must
> be treated with respect. The Talmud (Shevuot 35a-b) makes it clear
> that this prohibition applies only to seven Biblical names of G-d and
> not to other names or attributes of G-d, which may be freely written.
> The prohibition was later codified by Maimonides ([Mishneh Torah,
> Yesodei HaTorah 6:1-2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Six.htm)). The practice of writing "G-d" is supported in
> Shut Achiezer, 3:32, end, where it is endorsed and accepted as the
> prevailing custom. Rambam cites Deut. 12-03:04, which states "and you
> shall destroy the names of pagan gods from their places. You shall not
> do similarly to G-d your Lord." The intent of this is to create an
> atmosphere of respect for G-d's name vs pagan gods' names.
>
> As a result of this, people acquired the habit of not writing the full
> name down in the first place. Strictly speaking, this only
> applies to Hebrew on a permanent medium, but many people are
> careful beyond the minimum, and have applied it to non-Hebrew
> languages. Hence, "G-d". One explanation is that using G-d is a
> reminder that anything which we may say about G-d is necessarily
> metaphorical. Spelling out the Name (even in a language other than
> Hebrew) would imply that one could speak meaningfully (not just
> metaphorically) about G-d.
>
> However, the [Shach (Yoreh De'a 179:11)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%22%D7%9A_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%98#%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%97) ruled that "God" spelled in a
> foreign language does NOT have the status of a "shem" and thus
> may be erased, lehatkhila. There is a story about Rav Soloveitchik
> (z"l) intentionally writing GOD on the board while teaching a class
> and then just as deliberately and intentionally erasing it, so as
> to demonstrate by his own example that this was not a halakhically
> a problem.

Comment: Whats the point of "G-d" then? Seems like a larp.

Comment: @Anon see: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/486809/jewish/Why-Write-Gd-Instead-of-G-o-d.htm

Comment: Just adding, in theory the Gentiles would not be obliged to sanctify the name of God, so if there is any prohibition, it refers to the Jews, Elohim and their abbreviations from which God is derived and not just proper names. Now Hashem does not because it is not a biblical name.

Comment: @Thales That is very interesting. I'd like to read [or listen if it comes from a lecture] more about that theory.

Comment: @Anon, sorry, what is a "larp" in this context? "Live action role play"? Also this point about "G-d" is interesting considering that "God" is a title and not a name(?)

Comment: @neo Yeah, that is right. At first I thought it was something along the lines of a "messianic jew" who wears a yamulke while rejecting the talmud -- I would call that a larp given the yamulke is just for show, and the talmud is where the custom comes from [afaik]. I thought the chabad article though gave a good rationalization, and I also do think its... interesting that you point out the title/name distinction. Never thought of that before.